# What could be best solution for this in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying the following code and it works OK in a static way.
I want it to more dynamic approach 
following is my code:

```
url = 'abcxzy.com'   
r1 = request.post(url,header={'Cookie':'xyz'}    
r2 = request.post(url,header={'Cookie':'abcd'}    
try:
    r1.json()
    print("Receving JSON from server 1")    
    r2.json()
    print("Receving JSON from server 2")    
except:
    print("Server 1 is down")
    print("Server 1 is down")
```

I have 2 problems:

- In future, if have more server to validate assume some 100 then what is the best approach.
- And the only server not responding the JSON request must go to exception block and print the statement only for not responding JSON server name, currently, if any server is not getting JSON response it is entering the exception block and printing both print statements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some sort of a loop, for each of your url's to ensure you do the same thing for each of them.

I am unable to test any of this, so the following is just to give you an idea:

```
# list of dictionaires, containling both url and cookie
urls = [{'url':'abc.com', 'cookie':'bla1'},
        {'url':'def.com', 'cookie':'bla2'},
        {'url':'ghi.com', 'cookie':'bla3'}]

#declare a variable/list for your responses
responses = []

# for each dictionary in the list, loop through
# and do the request/json 
for url in urls:
    try:
        r = request.post(url['url'],header={'Cookie':url['cookie']})
        # append your json to the responses list
        responses.append(r.json())
    except:
        print('Something wrong with {} using {} cookie'.format(url['url'], url['cookie']))

for response in responses:
    print(response)
```

But what you should do is capture the specific `exception` in the `except` statement, not just a blanket-catch-all. And you should have a look at `r.status_code` in the `except` block, and also `r.raise_for_status()` in your `except` block

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try out it and let you comment back on it The url and cookie what i mentioned in code is just an example. Secondly  always r.status_code will have some response, so only I am validating using JSON() response to make sure that response is not coming means I can print it is DOWN